# How to use libpcap to sniff on multiple devices?

Tags: libpcap

I am trying to create a sniffer that can sniff on multiple devices.  In my code the program will receive a list of devices that a user wants to sniff on.  I take the list of device and store it into an array that I use to loop through and pass along to a function that creates the pcap_t handle like the function below:

```
void *startPcapProcess(char * dev){
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];     /* error buffer */
    pcap_t *handle;                    /* packet capture handle  */

/* filter expression [3] */
char filter_exp[] = "(dst port 53) and (udp[0xa] & 0x78 = 0x28)"; 

struct bpf_program fp;      /* compiled filter program (expression) */
bpf_u_int32 mask;           /* subnet mask */
bpf_u_int32 net;            /* ip */

printf("%s","startPacketProcess called\n");
printf("Device sent to startPacketProcess: %s\n", dev);
/* get network number and mask associated with capture device */
if (pcap_lookupnet(dev, &net, &mask, errbuf) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't get netmask for device %s: %s\n",
            dev, errbuf);
    net = 0;
    mask = 0;
}

/* open capture device */
handle = pcap_open_live(dev, SNAP_LEN, 1, 1000, errbuf);
if (handle == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open device %s: %s\n", dev, errbuf);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* make sure we're capturing on an Ethernet device [2] */
if (pcap_datalink(handle) != DLT_EN10MB) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s is not an Ethernet\n", dev);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* compile the filter expression */
if (pcap_compile(handle, &fp, filter_exp, 0, net) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't parse filter %s: %s\n",
        filter_exp, pcap_geterr(handle));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* apply the compiled filter */
if (pcap_setfilter(handle, &fp) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't install filter %s: %s\n",
        filter_exp, pcap_geterr(handle));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

pcap_freecode(&fp);

/* now we can set our callback function */
pcap_loop(handle, -1, process_packet, NULL);
printf("%s","End startPacketProcess call\n");

}
```

However, when I make a call to this function within my for loop it is only able to capture on one device since it seems to get stuck in the pcap_loop callback function.  As a result of this I tried to do multi threading and the for loop that I use to pass in all the devices to open and capture to goes through the loop, but the pcap_loop callback function does not seem to execute.  The following code shows my use of multi threading:

```
for (i = 0; i < numDevice; i++){
        printf("Device returned by getDevices call: %s\n", deviceList[i]);
        printf("%s","Entering for loop\n");
        pthread_create(&tid, thAttr, startPacketProcess,(void*)deviceList[i]);
    }
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and can you provide me with suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Linh

Answer (score 1):

`process_packet` might be the problem. Try getting the packet in the thread context.

```
  struct pcap_pkthdr *pkt_header;   
  u_char *pkt_data;         

  while ((retval = pcap_next_ex(mpPcap, &pkt_header, (const u_char **) &pkt_data)) >= 0)   {
    //Do Whatever
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `pcap_findalldevs()` or `pcap_findalldevs_ex()`